# Shell script to SSH through 3 servers

Tags: bash, shell, ssh, automation

As the title states I have been trying to SSH from server 1 to server 2 to server 3 using a shell script.
I have been able to get this working:

```
eval ssh-agent -s

ssh-agent

ssh-add -k key.pem

ssh -At -I key.pem root@server1 "ssh -At server2"
```

I can work off the terminal in server 2 fine doing this but I do not know how to continue this to get to server 3. And once there I will need to navigate to a folder and run a command `symfony cc`.

This is my first timing attempting a shell script so this is all new to me

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have passwrordless ssh set up before doing anything. You can use `ssh-copy-id username@servername` to do this. After that, the following command will work `ssh root@server1 \ ssh root@server2 \ ssh root@server3 "command"`

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the same key can be used for each step, it can be as simple as

```
eval $(ssh-agent -s)
ssh-add -k key.pem
ssh -A -Jserver1,server2 server3
```

You'll simply try to connect to `server3`; the `-J` option tells `ssh` to tunnel through `server1` and `server2` first. The `-A` option should ensure that each of the intermediate servers has access to your local agent.